# Is there a built-in/easy LDU decomposition method in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I see cholesky decomposition in numpy.linalg.cholesky, but could not find a LDU decompositon. Can anyone suggest a function to use?

Comment: Take a look here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.cholesky.html

Comment: This is not an off topic request, there is a function in scipy which does this. Whoever voted to close - you don't seem to know that, you probably shouldn't be viewing this tag.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ It does fall under "..request for API.."; although that's sort of nebulous.

Comment: @user2357112 I assumed pivot and normal were the same since the permutation matrix was indeed being set to the identity. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Wrong default username guy.

Comment: @user2357112 Just get a username already, or I'll start calling you Twickler.

Comment: When Scipy version 1.1 is out, `scipy.linalg.ldl` will be available.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Scipy has an LU decomposition function: [`scipy.linalg.lu`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lu.html). Note that this also introduces a permutation matrix `P` into the mix. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23208848/525169) gives a nice explanation of why this happens.

If you specifically need LDU, then you can just normalize the `U` matrix to pull out `D`.

Here's how you might do it:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import scipy.linalg as la
>>> a = np.array([[2, 4, 5],
                  [1, 3, 2],
                  [4, 2, 1]])
>>> (P, L, U) = la.lu(a)
>>> P
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> L
array([[ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.5       ,  1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.25      ,  0.83333333,  1.        ]])
>>> U
array([[ 4. ,  2. ,  1. ],
       [ 0. ,  3. ,  4.5],
       [ 0. ,  0. , -2. ]])
>>> D = np.diag(np.diag(U))   # D is just the diagonal of U
>>> U /= np.diag(U)[:, None]  # Normalize rows of U
>>> P.dot(L.dot(D.dot(U)))    # Check
array([[ 2.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 1.,  3.,  2.],
       [ 4.,  2.,  1.]])
```

Comment: It'd be useful to demonstrate how to perform the normalization.

Comment: @user2357112 Done.

Comment: This looks like the best available built-in, but it's disappointing that it gives a non-identity permutation matrix for an input that looks like it could be LU factorized without one.

Comment: This only works for invertible matrices. When `a` is singular in your example U will have 0 entries on the diagonal, and the normalization procedure does not work.

Comment: I might be missing something, but P @ L just destroys the low-triangle structure?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]])
U = np.triu(A,1)
L = np.tril(A,-1)
D = np.tril(np.triu(A))
print(A)
print(L)
print(D)
print(U)
```

Comment: This isn't an LDU decomposition: it's just pulling out the upper and lower triangles and the diagonal of A. For an actual LDU decomposition, when you multiply L, D and U, you should recover A, i.e., `A = L @ D @ U`