# Scipy linalg LU decomposition gives different results to my textbook

Tags: python, numpy, math, matrix, scipy

I am working through the 5th ed of Linear Programming by Saul I. Gass.

He gives the following text and example:
"Given an n x n nonsingular matrix **A**, then **A** can be expressed as the product **A** = **LU**... ...if we let the diagonal elements of **U** (or **L**) be all equal to 1, then the **LU** decomposition will be unique..."

[image: A=LU]

I managed to get a reversible lower-upper decomposition with this code that I found from this SO question: [Is there a built-in/easy LDU decomposition method in Numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45450175/is-there-a-built-in-easy-ldu-decomposition-method-in-numpy?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But I still can't tell what is going on and why **L** and **U** are so different from my textbook. Can anybody explain this to me?

So this code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la
a = np.array([[1, 1, -1],
              [-2, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 1]])
(P, L, U) = la.lu(a)

print(P)
print(L)
print(U)

D = np.diag(np.diag(U))   # D is just the diagonal of U
U /= np.diag(U)[:, None]  # Normalize rows of U
print(P.dot(L.dot(D.dot(U))))    # Check
```

gives this output:

```
[[ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]]
[[ 1.   0.   0. ]
 [-0.5  1.   0. ]
 [-0.5  1.   1. ]]
[[-2.   1.   1. ]
 [ 0.   1.5 -0.5]
 [ 0.   0.   2. ]]
[[ 1.  1. -1.]
 [-2.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]]
```

Comment: Your textbook is not following conventions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a choice which matrix (**L** or **U**) should have ones on the diagonal. The textbook example chose **U** but scipy's implementation chose **L**. This explains the difference.

To illustrate the point, we can turn things around:

```
(P, L, U) = la.lu(a.T)

print(P.T)
# [[ 1.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  1.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  1.]]
print(L.T)
# [[ 1.          1.         -1.        ]
#  [ 0.          1.         -0.33333333]
#  [ 0.          0.          1.        ]]
print(U.T)
# [[ 1.  0.  0.]
#  [-2.  3.  0.]
#  [ 1.  0.  2.]]
```

By transposing the matrix we basically swapped **U** and **L** so that the other matrix gets ones on the diagonal. And, voila, the result is the same as in the textbook.

(Note that if the permutation matrix **P** was no identity matrix the results would look a little different.)