# Scipy LDL decomposition returning unexpected result

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, linear-algebra

I have generated a random 5*5 matrix `x` like so:

```
>>> x = np.random.randn(5,5)
```

And decomposed it using the [`scipy.linalg.ldl`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.ldl.html) decomposition like so:

```
>>> l, d, p = la.ldl(x)
```

Using `l`, `d` and `p` I want to return x. I thought I would be able to do the following:

```
>>> l[p,:] @ d @ l[p,:].transpose() - x
```

But this does not give me zero as I would have expected. Can anyone explain where I am going wrong?

My aim is to obtain the lower diagonal matrix `L` such that `x = LDL^T` without the need for the row permutation matrix `p`, but I am very confused as to what scipy is giving as output.

Comment: As pointed out by someone else, you need to supply a symmetric, positive definite matrix. To create an example, you just need to "square" a general matrix (maybe adding something to the diagonal to ensure that the eigenvalues are all nonzero). E.g. something like `X = <some matrix>; XX = transpose(X) . X; XX1 = XX + identity` (with made-up notation. I don't know what are these operations in Numpy/Scipy) and then you XX1 is symmetric and p.d., so you can go ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LDL decomposition algorithm only applies for Hermitian/symmetric matrices. You are passing it a matrix with random values which is very unlikely to be symmetric. In addition, the matrix multiplication should be performed without applying the permutation matrix to the lower triangular matrices.

When a non-symmetric matrix is passed to `scipy.linalg.ldl`, only the lower or upper triangular part of the matrix is referenced, depending on the value of the `lower` keyword argument, which defaults to `True`. We can see the effects of this with `np.isclose()`:

```
>>> x = np.random.randn(5,5)
>>> l, d, p = la.ldl(x)
>>> np.isclose(l.dot(d).dot(l.T) - x, 0)
[[ True False False False False]
 [ True  True False False False]
 [ True  True  True False False]
 [ True  True  True  True False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True]]
```

Here we see that the upper triangular part of the matrix has been assumed to be symmetric, and so the algorithm has returned values that would be correct if that were the case.

Below, we pass `la.ldl` an actual symmetric matrix, and obtain the expected result.

```
>>> x = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                  [2, 4, 5],
                  [3, 5, 6]])
>>> l, d, p = la.ldl(x)
>>> print(np.isclose(l.dot(d).dot(l.T) - x, 0))
[[ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]]
```

If you're looking for a decomposition into LDL^T in general, *without having permutations*, this reduces the field of matrices even further. Your matrix also needs to be [positive definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness_of_a_matrix).

Here is an example with one such matrix:

```
>>> x = np.array([[2, -1, 0],
                  [-1, 3, -1],
                  [0, -1, 4]])
>>> l, d, p = la.ldl(x)
>>> l
array([[ 1. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [-0.5,  1. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. , -0.4,  1. ]])
>>> d
array([[2. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 2.5, 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 3.6]])
>>> p
array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64)
```

As you can see, the permutation `p` is just `[0, 1, 2]`, and `l` is already lower triangular.

Comment: Just to add that it seems that even for positive definite matrices, sometimes the permutation array may be reordered. I notice that this is usually when the off-axis values are large (near the diagonal values). It might be due to the way the algorithm minimizes floating point errors, according to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208640/scipy-lu-factorization-permutation-matrix/23208848#23208848